# click then unclick jquery button not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to make a button which on one click it changes it's color, and on another click it returns to it's original form.
something like clicked and unclicked.

I added a JSfiddle for you to look at it.
https://jsfiddle.net/dw5y5xLx/3/

```
$('.genM').click(function() {

$('.genM').removeClass('selected');


$(this).addClass('selected');

});
```

thanks!

also, is there a way doing that by only using CSS HTML?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the JSfiddle?

Comment: where is JSfiddle /

Comment: What have you done so far ?

Comment: Is this what you want ? https://jsfiddle.net/dw5y5xLx/7/

Comment: You need to learn how to use jsfiddle in the first place ... jQuery should be embedded via the option settings in the JS tab, no `<script>` tags belong into the script tab (browser console would have told you about the syntax errors you are producing!) ... and finally, you want to use toggleClass. https://jsfiddle.net/dw5y5xLx/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery `hasClass` function can be helpful

```
$('.genM').click(function() {

    if($(this).hasClass('selected')){
            $(this).removeClass('selected');
    }else{
        $(this).addClass('selected');
    }

});
```

Comment: It would be more clean to use `$(this).toggleClass('selected');`

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen Yes..I do agree !

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.genM').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});
```

I have updated the js fiddle for you, please check  (https://jsfiddle.net/dw5y5xLx/15/)!

Answer (score 0):

**IDEA:**

> Is there a way doing that by only using CSS HTML?

Yes, there is a way how u could achieve that just by pure CSS and HTML. But, if you dont want to use js, you must have an HTML element that is able to keep the "pressed" or "unpressed" state all by itself, without js.

However, there is no such an HTML element, so you have to use something simmilar: **Checkbox**

`<input type="checkbox">` have "checked" and "unchecked" state and it is practicaly the same as "pressed" or "unpressed".

---

**SOLUTION:**

The trick is to stylize the ckeckbox with CSS so it visually appears as a pressed or unpressed button. [Here is an example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_switch.asp) how checkbox can be stylised - you need to modify the CSS in order to appear it like a button, not a toggle switch!

You will want to use CSS selectors like this (as shown in example):

```
input[type="checkbox"]:checked { ... },
input[type="checkbox"]:checked + .slider { ... },
```